# onchange refresh particular content php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The following image shows the part of my web page. I am developing my site using php.

[image]

If i select an option in the `draft` listmenu the options in the following field eg, pick 1, pick 2 will changed. I did this this using `onchange`. I get the the id from onchange and use that id in the select query to fetch the details from the database and the fetched data will be replaced in the below listmenus.

I need it to be done by refreshing that part only and not the whole page. Is there any possibility to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the question tag, you are already using jQuery. That's great.

Assuming the first select name is 'draft', that the other selects are contained in an element of id 'picks', and that that /picks.php?id=X will generate an appropriate replacement for #picks:

```
$('select[name=draft]').change(function() {
    $.get('/picks.php', {'id': $(this).val()}, function(data) {
        $('#picks').html(data);
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is. The technology to do so is called ajax. I recommend you look into a javascript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It will make the process much easier. The specific jQuery api reference you would need is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

For example in you could use something like this:

```
// Wait till the page has loaded
$.ready(function() {
  // create the on change event
  $('#draftID').on('change', function() {
    // get the new information from the server
    $.ajax({
      url: 'document.php?id=' + $('#draftID').val(),
      success: function(data){
        // this code is run when you get the reply;
        $('#someDivID').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```